# How can I make Outlook my default mail app in windows 10 (advanced knowledge necessary)?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-365

I have Thunderbird and now Outlook-365 on my system. I would like to change my default E-Mail App to Outlook.

- When you select "send to - Mail recipient" Outlook should open
- When you select from Excel - Share - Attach as a copy, the Excel should be sent with Outlook

I am on Windows 10 20H2 and Outlook 365.

Of course the defaults have been set:

[image]
[image]

I also tried to change the "send to" to Outlook, but Windows says, the app is

[image]

[image]

When I explicitly try to select
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\outlook.exe
I get:

[image]

I also deleted all entries named "mailTo" in the registry.

Still everything is routed to Thunderbird.

I am out of ideas.

So, how do I change it?

Comment: May I know if you set Outlook as the default mail client via Outlook options?

Comment: I did, though I think it has no effect in Windows 10. I also disabled default in Thunderbird.

Comment: Finally figured it out: Reset to Microsoft defaults. Strangely switching E-Mail default apps did not do anything.